# SignalR not broadcasting to clients - (mobile browser) connected through wifi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, signalr

I have been trying to broadcast message to all clients who connected to my hub, all desktop browsers (IE 9, Chrome 20.x) receives the message except mobile browsers who are connected through WiFi. I deployed application in IIS7 and using accessing it within LAN.

So the server code which I have is as follows -

```
[HubName("notifications")]
public class Notifications : Hub
{
    try
    {
      using (var context = new xxxEntities())
        {
         // EF code that post the record to the database
             Clients.taskAdded(message);
             return true;
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Caller.reportError("Unable to create notification message. Make sure title length is between 10 and 140");
        return false;
      }
```

Client side code -

```
//Handlers for our Hub callbacks  
//Invoked from our TaskHub.cs  
this.hub.taskAdded = function (t) {
messages.push(new notificationViewModel(t.Id, t.Message, t.User, t.Notified, self));
//if (guid != test.guid) //notify all clients except the caller
};
```

This all works well on desktop browsers, I have used knockout.js to refresh data model bounded to HTML elements (ex. list). As and when the task got added in the database all desktop browser clients got refreshed except mobile one.

so you have any clue why mobile browsers doesn't get notified?

**Update -** 
I have same issue in IE 9 as well, got stack copied from developer tools of IE

It uses Long Polling transport, I believe IE doesn't support web sockets hence signalR switch transport to "Long Polling"

Here is the URL that it tries after every 2 seconds

URL - /m.Notifications/signalr/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionId=311eed98-4e1d-4a0c-a012-2a41b20eded0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notifications%22%7D%5D&messageId=18&tid=7

Method - GET
Result - 500 (Http response code)
Initiator - JS Library XMLHttpRequest

### *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

**Stack Trace:**

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
System.Web.HttpContext.GetWebSocketInitStatus() +251
System.Web.HttpContextWrapper.get_IsWebSocketRequest() +46
SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetResponse.get_IsClientConnected() +48
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat.AddConnection(ITrackingConnection connection) +280
SignalR.Transports.LongPollingTransport.ProcessReceiveRequest(ITransportConnection connection, Action postReceive) +38
SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.Interleave(Func`3 before, Func`1 after, T arg, TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs) +181
SignalR.Transports.LongPollingTransport.ProcessRequest(ITransportConnection connection) +295
SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context) +892
SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContextBase context) +866
System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.BeginTask(Func`1 taskFunc, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50     System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12519412
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +288
```

Comment: Can you clarify on which mobile browsers you see this behavior?

Comment: I have Samsung Galaxy S II, so it should be Chrome

Comment: I'd suggest testing in other mobile browsers, to see if it is limited to Chrome only. You can also use the Remote Debugging capabilities of Chrome on Android to see what exactly is going on: https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging

Answer (score 0):

New build works well, I got latest source downloaded from https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/
I see there are fixes for Long Polling transport, presumed this issue also has got resolved

I would be scrutinize further what was fixed since 0.5.2

**One observation**  - In IE 9 developer tools under network tab, you will see one request which is running (mostly last request) with status "Pending", the status got changed immediately when you either receive notification/ or you send something to the server, this should be long polling technique for browser who doesn't support web socket.